# Separating work in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, pycharm

I'm playing around with Mercurial and I have a question about separating work for various tickets (I use PyCharm as my IDE, but this is more of a general Mercurial question).

My workflow goes like this: claim a ticket (bug, feature, refactor, etc), create an associated bookmark, hack away, push my bookmark up for code review, code is ready for integration testing. During integration testing I take all the bookmarks, merge them and test.

My problem is when I push my code up. The first bookmark that I push up continues along the default branch, while my 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc bookmarks I push create new heads along the default branch. This is great because if during testing and a bug is discovered, the associated bookmark's code can be removed and the remaining code can continue to be tested / released. (IE: I can pick and choose which bookmarks to merge and test) The problem is with that first bookmark. If I understand Mercurial, you can only merge heads, which means the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc bookmarks that I want to merge and test must be merged with the first bookmark that was pushed up; which means if I need to rip out the code from the first bookmark, I can't (IE: the first bookmark **must** be part of the merged group).

Now, this can be worked around by using branches. A new branch is a new 'head', so I can pick and choose which branches to merge and test. However, it is my understanding that branches in Mercurial are suppose to be a long time thing (like having QA, testing, and release branches), and not for minor things like bug fixes.

Should I just use branches, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait, I figured it out; I'm just being silly, sorry about that guys.

So for future reference:
My problem was that I was unable to cherry pick which bookmarks to merge because the first bookmark would continue along the 'main line of development' and I would have to update to it (because it's a head, and I can only merge heads). **However**, there is absolutely nothing preventing me from updating to a different head (such as to bookmark #2) and merging in whatever bookmarks I want. IE: For some reason, it was stuck in my head that I had to update to the 'main line' head (which contains code from bookmark #1) to merge, when I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can merge any arbitrary versions unless one is a direct descendent of the other.

A bookmark only becomes active, if you update to it.

If you want the bookmark to NOT become active, simply update to the version it is attached to by referring to the hash.

From what I understand, you are actually *missing* a bookmark. A bookmark which indicates the approved head and does not contain any testing code from your bug fix heads. You could bookmark that revision with the special @ bookmark.

Comment: I have a bookmark at the 'beginning' where all tickets 'branch' from (the 'beginning' bookmark is almost always at the latest release). When the first ticket bookmark is made and changes have been committed, a new head is **not** created (the commit becomes the new tip, which I don't want) while additional bookmarks do create a new head. Since I can only merge heads, I must update to a head (which now contains the code from the first bookmark, since it did not make a new head). IE: The first ticket **must** integrated.

Comment: As explained: your understanding is at least partially wrong! You can merge an arbitrary changeset with any other arbitrary changeset as long as they are not linearliy related, e.g. one is a descendant of the other. This is independent whether one or the other or neither is a head changeset or not

Comment: However, shouldn't you test all your bug fixes individually, thus test each of your (bookmarked) heads individually? Also checkout the meaning of the @ bookmark. It is not just like any bookmark. It indicates the default revision to update to

Comment: In this case I don't think my understanding was wrong. The problem is that after pushing the first bookmark, it doesn't create a separate head, it continues on the existing head (IE: they are linearly related and therefore I can't merge the first bookmark in to my 'release candidate' bookmark). I realized just a few minutes ago that this is a non-issue (see my answer for details).

I do test them individually, but I also do an integration test to make sure that code from fix A doesn't change/break code that fix B relies on.

I'll check out the @ bookmark, didn't realize there were conventions.